# Mobicents - RestComm Issue

Tags: sip, voip, mobicents, restcomm

I am following Tutorials by RestComm for their Mobicents Implementation. I successully bind and register users through CURL for Hello-World demo and DTMF Demo.

Whenever i place a call on sip:1234@127.0.0.1:5080 or sip:3333@127.0.0.1:5080 i receive following exception

```
    13:29:58,728 INFO  [InitialRequestDispatcher] Request event dispatched to RestComm
    13:29:58,767 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter] org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war\/audio/one-second-silence.wav
    13:29:58,768 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter] org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war\/audio/one-second-silence.wav
    13:29:58,768 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter] org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war\/audio/one-second-silence.wav
    13:29:58,768 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter] org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war\/audio/one-second-silence.wav
    13:29:58,769 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter] org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war\/audio/one-second-silence.wav
    13:29:58,769 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter] org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war\/audio/one-second-silence.wav
    13:29:58,769 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter] org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war\/audio/one-second-silence.wav
```

The Headers of the call are fine i think,

> 13:42:05,514 INFO  [SIPTransactionStack]
>
> > ;tag=1545 To: 
> >     Call-ID: 23338 CSeq: 20 OPTIONS Accept: application/sdp Max-Forwards:
> >     70 User-Agent: Linphone/3.5.2 (eXosip2/3.6.0) Content-Length: 0
>
> ]]>
>
> 13:42:05,518 INFO  [SIPTransactionStack]
>
> > ;tag=97936972_57a5b08a_d49670a8-7483-482d-b493-47b6f0ffb64a Via: SIP/2.0/UDP
> >     192.168.132.86:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK24540;received=127.0.0.1 CSeq: 20 OPTIONS Call-ID: 23338 From:
> >     ;tag=1545 Content-Length: 0
>
> ]]>
>
> 13:42:05,524 INFO  [InitialRequestDispatcher] Request event dispatched
>   to RestComm 13:42:05,546 INFO  [SIPTransactionStack]
>
> > ;tag=32134 To:
> >      Call-ID: 23679 CSeq: 20 INVITE Contact:
> >      Content-Type: application/sdp Allow:
> >     INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,NOTIFY,MESSAGE,SUBSCRIBE,INFO
> >     Max-Forwards: 70 User-Agent: Linphone/3.5.2 (eXosip2/3.6.0) Subject:
> >     Phone call Content-Length: 479
>
> v=0 o=toto 294 294 IN IP4 192.168.132.86 s=Talk c=IN IP4
>   192.168.132.86 t=0 0 m=audio 7078 RTP/AVP 112 111 110 3 0 8 101 a=rtpmap:112 speex/32000 a=fmtp:112 vbr=on a=rtpmap:111 speex/16000
>   a=fmtp:111 vbr=on a=rtpmap:110 speex/8000 a=fmtp:110 vbr=on
>   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000 a=fmtp:101 0-11 m=video 9078 RTP/AVP
>   103 99 98 a=rtpmap:103 VP8/90000 a=rtpmap:99 MP4V-ES/90000 a=fmtp:99
>   profile-level-id=3 a=rtpmap:98 H263-1998/90000 a=fmtp:98 CIF=1;QCIF=1
>   ]]>
>
> 13:42:05,558 INFO  [SIPTransactionStack]
>
> > Via: SIP/2.0/UDP
> >     192.168.132.86:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK2917;received=127.0.0.1 CSeq: 20 INVITE Call-ID: 23679 From:
> >     ;tag=32134 Content-Length: 0
>
> ]]>
>
> 13:42:05,573 INFO  [SIPTransactionStack]
>
> > ;tag=51502709_57a5b08a_2e371fbf-827f-4e13-be37-4ba38c93a9c9 Via: SIP/2.0/UDP
> >     192.168.132.86:5060;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bK2917;received=127.0.0.1 CSeq: 20 INVITE Call-ID: 23679 From:
> >     ;tag=32134 Contact: 
> >     Content-Length: 0
>
> ]]>
>
> 13:42:05,576 INFO  [InitialRequestDispatcher] Request event dispatched
>   to RestComm 13:42:05,593 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter]
>   org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at
>   index 7:
>   file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war/audio/one-second-silence.wav
>   13:42:05,634 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter]
>   org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at
>   index 7:
>   file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war/audio/one-second-silence.wav
>   13:42:05,634 WARN  [RcmlInterpreter]
>   org.mobicents.servlet.sip.restcomm.xml.VisitorException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at
>   index 7:
>   file://C:\restcomm-saas-jboss-1.0.0.CR2-SNAPSHOT\server\default\deploy\restcomm.war/audio/one-second-silence.wav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resoved it by moving sound files to another directory and not the war file. 
and inside restcomm.xml i changed their path like this.

From

> ${restcomm:home}/audio/one-second-silence.wav

TO

> C:/restcomm/sounds/one-second-silence.wav

I guess, it was an issue with Windows OS only, this same example must have run like charm on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the ready made AMI on Amazon Marketplace https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00FFHJ6SU/ref=sp_mpg_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-3 to avoid this kind of issues as everything is pre configured correctly